# Failed to run File Watcher 'Sass' in PhpStorm

Tags: css, sass, phpstorm

I have problem when compiling Sass into CSS.

```
Failed to run File Watcher 'Sass'.
The watcher has been disabled.
Error: Cannot run program "cmd.exe" (in directory "D:\Program\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\XXX\sass"): CreateProcess error=2
```

[image]

Comment: *"Cannot run program `cmd.exe`"* -- looks like some permission error. If you run IDE as Administrator -- will it work? Anyway -- try restarting your computer -- often helps in resolving "used to work fine just a moment ago" issues.

Comment: is `cmd.exe` on your system `%PATH%`? Can you start it by typing `cmd` in the Run system prompt, for example?